# Change of name in visa and passport

Tags: visas, usa

I would like to ask for clarification regarding changing my name from Maria Elena to Melita. The name printed on my US visa is Maria Elena, while in my new passport it is Melita. In my amended birth certificate, on the lower portion it shows an annotation for the name change, which states the change from Maria Elena to Melita. Is there a discrepancy here?

Comment: Yes. You absolutely need a new visa without a doubt. A simple google search will find State department source for that. Your visa is no longer valid.